# Can the contents of a usercontrol be modified at runtime in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, user-controls

I need to display pop ups in my app. So I have user controls to make customised pop ups. Every pop up shows a different message and different set of buttons. Can I reuse the same xaml to alter the text and make new buttons? Or do I have to create seperate usercontrols?

```
 <Grid Height="250" Width="480">
    <Canvas Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF121111" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Button Content="Buy" x:Name="buttonBuy" Click="btnBuyNow_Click" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource UserControlBuy}" MinWidth="96" MinHeight="98" FontFamily="{StaticResource CicleFina}" FontSize="18.667" Canvas.Left="189" Canvas.Top="141" Height="98" Width="96" Foreground="#FF0E0C0C">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/02/but_bg_trial_buy.png"/>
            </Button.Background>                
        </Button>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="21.333" Padding="10" Text="Your trial period is over. Please purchase the full version" Height="141" Width="479"  Foreground="#D48394" FontFamily="{StaticResource PeaSnow}" TextAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

This is how i've called the pop up in the app. .

```
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        BuyNowUserControl content = new BuyNowUserControl(popup);
        // set the width of the popup to the width of the screen
        content.Width = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
        popup.Child = content;
        popup.VerticalOffset = 300;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Thanks

Alfah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can re-use them. I would do the following:

1. Create dependency properties on your user control for the customizable text you require.
2. Set the UserControl's DataContext to itself
3. Replace your hard-coded text in the above XAML with a binding to the dependency property added in (1)
4. You can now set the text on the user control instance after you have created it. The binding will ensure that the UI reflects this.

It is actually quite a bit of work to achieve this, so worth evaluating the benefit.

Comment: :D Thanks! :D Phew looks like lots to do :D